# Prevent Android Webview from changing font-size (Computed Style)

Tags: android, css

I have a webpage which is displayed by Android application via Webview component.

It decides to change the font-size so the text of 16px has font-size=14px (I can see it when I inspect the element with weinre. It has 16px but in computed style it has 14px).

I wouldn't like the Webview to decide what is better at all. So how can I fix the problem?

Remark: In this specific case the change causes the text not to be vertical aligned, because after the change the line-height doesn't adjust the font-size. It is just one of the cases and I would like to stop Webview from changing the css values.

Comment: what metatags does the webview use ? eg for viewport?

Comment: Do you mean html meta tags? The webpage has `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems to be due to the WebView respecting the system font size setting (which can be altered at: Settings > Display > Font size).

[image: Android Font size setting]

Several bug reports have been submitted in various places ([for example](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=512989))

> In order to reproduce the problem you have to scale down the system font size to small or minimum.

...

> Okay, I can repro if I change Settings > Display > Font size. It doesn't repro in Chrome, but then Chrome doesn't seem to respect "Font size" in the first place. I'm pretty busy right now, so it may be a while before I can investigate further.

Try setting your system font size to "Small" or "Medium" and test your app.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same behavior and solved it by changing TextZoom in the WebView Settings. On my app, the default value seems to be linked to the system font size setting. Set it to 100 to prevent the webview from changing the font size.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setTextZoom(int)

Answer (score 1):

This issue only affects pages viewed in a webview  and not the android browser. It possibly only affects a subset of devices. Has anyone else seen this problem?

I'm seeing my device transform fonts as follows:

> 16px -> 14px
>   14px -> 12px
>   12px -> 10px

I'm trying to force my page to render fonts at 12px across all devices. Here's a potential solution (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //set font-size to 12px
    $('html').css('font-size', "12px")

    //See what font-size is computed by the webview
    var fs = parseFloat($('html').css('font-size'));

    //If the webview is being naughty, compensate for it
    if (fs == 10) 
    {
        $('html').css('font-size', "14px");
    }
}
```